# syntax error unexpected T_ELSE

Tags: php

I have been checking this code for ages trying to find the cause of this error. It is saying unexpected T_ELSE and it is pointing to the last else in the code. Can someone point out my mistake. many thanks

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

// AFTER SUCCESSFUL QUERY
if (mysql_num_rows() == 0)
{
    echo '<div class="no-rec">No Record Found !</div>';
}
else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsd))
    {
        $ticket  = $row['ticket_frm'];
        $rowdate = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['date_frm']));
        $id      = $row['id_frm'];
        $from    = $row['from_frm'];
        $subject = $row['subject_frm'];
        $message = $row['message_frm'];

        $myString = <<<ENDMYSTRING
          <div class="each_rec">
          <div class="record blue" data-message="$message" data-subject="$subject" data-rowdate="$rowdate" data-from="$from">
          <img src="images/sml_new_mail_icon.gif" class="mailIcon" alt="" /><span class="iconSubject">$subject</span>
          <div class="rowdate">$rowdate</div>
          <span class="mailFrom">$from</span>
          </div>
          <br />
ENDMYSTRING;
          echo $myString;
    }
}

else

{

  echo 'you must enter a ticket#';

    //$sql = "select * from contact_frm";
    //var_dump(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: You have a 2nd else... check some lines below ENDMYSTRING

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: `if...else` covers *all* execution paths. What do you expect the 2nd `else` to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (mysql_num_rows() == 0) {

} else {
    ^ maybe here you could put elseif()
} else {
   // or just remove this else
}
```

Comment: what I am wanting happen is that if the first statement ==0 then display echo else if there is result echo result and the last else is to echo if there are no results of search. I have tried elseif(mysql_num_rows() > 0) in place of second else but now get unexpected $end. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. Could you rephrase. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you already have an else for your if (mysql_num_rows() == 0) test, just before your while; and then you provide another else for the "must provide ticket"

Perhaps you meant

```
elseif (mysql_num_rows() >= 1)
```

before the while loop

Answer (score 1):

You have what appears to be an `if-else-else` statement. I'm not aware of *any* language where that's valid :-)

You need to rethink your logic or your use of language elements.

Making some intelligent guesses here (which I realise is fraught with danger), the fact that you're checking the rows returned right up front seems to indicate that an `else` block stating there's no ticket number entered should have been done long before this point.

So it's possibly a cut'n'paste error or you've inserted the `if-else` at the wrong point, or you're missing another `if` before the one you have which has your current one in the `true` block.

The first thing I'd do is just get rid of the second `else` bit altogether, and start from there.

Then, if there's a logic problem, post another question here and turn us loose on it.

Answer (score 0):

here you have added two else clauses.